Solving linear system of equations with constraints on unknowns
I would like to solve a system of linear equations $y=Uh$ for an unknown vector $h$, where I have a few constraints on some of the elements of $h$.
Let us consider a small example: $y$ is a vector of size $N$, $U$ is a matrix of size $N \times 9$ and $h$ is a vector of size $9$, where $N>9$. Here, I have few constraints on the vector $h$. If the first three elements are $a, b, c$, then the next three elements should be $pa^2, pb^2, pc^2$, where $p$ is a non-zero scaling factor. The last three elements should then be $2pab, 2pac, 2pbc$. How do I use such constraints on parameters using another parameter of an unknown vector? Could someone help me with this?

You have more than 9 constraints and only 4 variables... Most probably your solution does not exists

I have 4 variables $a,b,c,p$ and 6 constraints. Is it not possible also using optimization?
